# Retrieving php stream errors in PHP extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I have a PHP extension that write files,

```
 stream = php_stream_open_wrapper(file_path, "a", REPORT_ERRORS | IGNORE_URL_WIN, NULL);            
 if (stream == NULL)
 {
    zend_error(E_WARNING, "Fail to open file stream of %s!", file_path);        
 }
```

The code above sometimes fail with `Permission Denied` error, and I need to notify end users about that.

So far I could use the `REPORT_ERRORS` flag that let PHP print errors in the stream functions directly,

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Fail to open file stream of /opt/rasp/log/plugin/plugin20171219.log! in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Since Functions like `perror / GetLastError` does not seem to exist in PHP, I can't just do a `snprintf` and build a custom error message

So how can I merge those two messages into a single one? (which is more meaningful)